# Link to a HTML page inside a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to link to a HTML file from a JavaScript on-click function. For that I used following function.

```
 onClick: function () {
                document.link("about.html");
               }
```

But this is not working. So how can I add link inside of onClick function. Can anyone help me.

Comment: `document.location = "about.html";`

Comment: Do you want to redirect to new page on click? If so, use window.location.href = "about.html";

Comment: @ChrisG this work fine, If you can post this as an answer I can mark this as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: I'm 100% sure this question is a duplicate. I can't find an older version right now though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jumping to a new HTML page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442384/jumping-to-a-new-html-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I use this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Go to page" onclick="location.href='mypage.html'"/>
```

Anyway u can try:

```
onClick: function () {
                location.href("about.html");
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onclick` property of a button element in HTML that will trigger a function when the button is pressed.

```
<button onclick="myFunc()">click me</button>
```

In your JavaScript file, you can then create the myFunc() function that will be called and executed soon after.

```
function myFunc() {
    window.location = "otherpage.html";
}
```

[According to W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/browsers.html#dom-location) it's safer for cross-browser compatibility to use window.location rather than document.location.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick:function(){
 window.navigate('your_url');
}
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:-

```
 <input type="button" value="Go to page" onclick="openUrl()"/>

    function openUrl() {
              window.open("about.html");
    //or
    //window.location.href= "about.html";
        }
```