# How to redirect to another html file in the same directory which is located inside a folder using js?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

here's the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form-marksheet">
        <div class="name">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="roll-no">
            <p>Roll No.</p>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="subject-english">
            <p>Marks for English</p>
            <input type="text"> 
        </div>
        <div class="subject-science">
            <p>Marks for Science</p>
            <input type="text"> 
        </div>
        <div class="subject-math">
            <p>Marks for math</p>
            <input type="text"> 
        </div>
        <div class="btn-trigger-update">
            <button onclick="updateScreen()">Get your marksheet</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the js file

```js
// Global variables

const student_name = document.getElementById("name")
const roll_no = document.getElementById("roll-no")
const english = document.getElementById("subject-english")
const science = document.getElementById("subject-science")
const math = document.getElementById("subject-math")

// Functions

function updateScreen() {
    
}
```

so when updateScreen is called, basically when the `get your marksheet` is pressed, i want to redirect to another file called ms.html which is in the same directory as the index.html. And yes, this all things are in a folder called `input-page`. I have tried `location.href = "ms.html"`, `location.assign(ms.html)`. Both of them don't work. Can anyone show me how to redirect to another html file using js?

and here's style.css too

```css
/* Font imports */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anek+Latin:wght@600&family=Kanit:wght@300&family=Open+Sans&family=PT+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@300;500&family=Roboto+Mono:wght@700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@300;900&family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');

/* Styling */

* {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }
body {text-align: center;}
form {display: inline-block;}
```

this isn't required, but I gave anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using:

```
window.location.href = "ms.html";
```

Here is a reference to a similar article with more details: [Jumping to a new HTML page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442384/jumping-to-a-new-html-page-with-javascript)